# geocoding an IP and save using model forms

Tags: django, django-forms, geocoding, geoip

i have this thing in my models.py file

```
        user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', unique = True) 
        latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=6)
        longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=6)
        Availability  = models.CharField(max_length=8,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank= False, null=False)
        Status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True, null= True)
```

and in forms.py i have

```
class registerForm(forms.ModelForm):

      class Meta:
        model=register
          fields = ('latitude', 'longitude', 'Availability', 'Status')
```

now what i want here is to geocode the Ip address of the user and get the latitude and longitude automatically after geocoding the IP and save it to the database. i dont want to allow the user to enter the latitide and longitude manually as it will be an odd one and definately nobody will like to do it manually. 
i am using GeoIP to geocode the IP address. and in my views.py i have

```
def Userlocation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        rform = registerForm(data = request.POST)
        if rform.is_valid():
            register = rform.save(commit=False)
            register.user=request.user
            register.save()
            return render_to_response('home.html')
    else:
        rform = registerForm() 
    return render_to_response('status_set.html',{'rform':rform})
```

i am looking for a way to automatically get the lat,lon from the GeoIP and place it in the latitude longitude field in forms so that the users do not have to manually enter it. and then after entering the status and availability the forms can be saved to database. 
any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the save method of form to populate latitude & longitude

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
class registerForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model=register
        fields = ('Availability', 'Status')

    def save(self, ip_address, *args, **kwargs):
        g = GeoIP()
        lat, lon = `get the lat & lng`
        user_location = super(registerForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user_location.latitude = lat
        user_location.longitude = lon
        user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i have overwrite the save method but the django barks as "save() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)"

Comment: you might have got it working by now, if not while calling the save method from the view pass the ip_address from request as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
register = rform.save(commit=False)
```

to

```
register = rform.save(ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```