# trying to auto populate fields using django views

Tags: django, django-views, geoip

my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281754/geocoding-an-ip-and-save-using-model-forms) question em using geoip to find the latitide and longitude of a user through IP address. i am doing something like this in my views

```
g=Geoip()
lat,lon=g.lat_lon(some ip)
```

here i want  the forms fields to be filled in automatically 
something like

```
 latitude=lat
 longitude=lon
 userform.save()
```

and dont want to overwrite the save method as i am  fairly new to django and no idea about how they work. i tried the above link code but unable to make it work for me.
how can i autopopulate the latitude and longitude fields in views.py

Answer (score 5):

Ah, just dive right in. Unless you do something really stupid you're not going to hurt anything. BTW, "stupid" includes doing this on your production site with an un-backed up database.

An important point to remember is that you're not *overwriting* the `save()` method, you're supplying a class-specific version of it which can, in turn, call the parent's `save()` method. E.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   ...
   def save(self):
      # whatever you need to do to the object before the save
      super(MyModel, self).save() # replace MyModel with *your* class name
```

Alternatively, you can call `super()` first and then do stuff afterward. If all your routine did was call `super()` you would have a correct (but useless) `save()` method.

See [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) for more insight/info.

Comment: thats sounds gud bhut what should i write in views.py

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. You can write anything you like in your view; it's just code. I assumed (always a bad thing) that your `some ip` value was *in* the form (you didn't say where it came from) and that you wanted to auto populate additional model fields when you did the `save()`.