# Placing GeoIP IP/lat_lon Information in Django Forms

Tags: python, django, geolocation, django-forms

I'm currently working on an application where I want to automatically insert the latitude and longitude coordinates into a user form. I found a previous post here which aims to do almost exactly what I'm attempting to accomplish [geocoding an IP and save using model forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281754/geocoding-an-ip-and-save-using-model-forms) but I seem to be making an error in the process. I've installed GeoIP to track the IP and lat, lon from the user.

Here's the view code:

```
@login_required
def submit_story(request):
if request.method =="POST":
    story_form = StoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if story_form.is_valid():
        new_story = story_form.save(ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        new_story.author = request.user
        new_story.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/report/all/")
else: # GET request
    story_form = StoryForm()
return render_to_response("report/report.html", {'form': story_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And this is the form, where I believe the issue lies:

```
class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        exclude = ('author','latitude', 'longitude')

    def save(self, ip_address, *args, **kwargs):
        g = GeoIP()
        lat, lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)
        user_location = super(StoryForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user_location.latitude = lat
        user_location.longitude = lon
        user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/report/report/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'profiles',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'stentorian.report',
 'south',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'gmapi',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
 ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
   23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/myname/Development/stentorian/../stentorian/report/views.py" in submit_story
  30.             new_story = story_form.save(ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
 File "/Users/myname/Development/stentorian/../stentorian/report/forms.py" in save
  16.         lat, lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)

Exception Type: TypeError at /report/report/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is my first time wading into geolocation and first Django project, so I'm quite sure the mistake is simple (perhaps I need to split the tuple, not sure).

Comment: The actual traceback with the error would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
lat, lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)
```

is causing the exception because g.lat_lon() is returning None, so its result
can't be unpacked into `lat` and `lon`.

It should return something like `(32.0434235, 43.532522)` for example.

This means that you are either passing an invalid argument to `g.lat_lon()`, or that
for some other reason it can't resolve the lat/lon.

**UPDATE:**

```
new_story = story_form.save(ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

I suppose you run this from your local workstation and in that case the
`request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` has the value `"127.0.0.1"` which obviously
is not something that `g.lat_lon()` can resolve.

When in development the settings.DEBUG == True. So you could do the following

```
from django.conf import settings

def submit_story(request):
    remote_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    if settings.DEBUG:
        # We are in debug mode, so we set it to a dummy value.
        remote_addr = 'google.com'

    if request.method =="POST":
        story_form = StoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if story_form.is_valid():
            new_story = story_form.save(ip_address=remote_addr)
```

Comment: So, considering the view defines ip_address and ip_address is passed into the arguments for lat_lon(), what other argument might be valid/missing/needed? Very stumped.

Comment: @WhyNot This would work if the client(browser) connection was coming from a valid publicly addressable IP. You could pass a dummy 'google.com' as a parameter, instead of `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`, when in development(DEBUG=True in django settings).

Comment: That's quite likely. Is there a way to set the value of request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] to something static to see if it works otherwise? Edit: I think you just answered my question. Will try (ip_address=request.META['google.com']).

Comment: Getting issues with the ip_address from the view not being passed as an argument to the form save. I changed that back to commit false and it also says not getting an argument of 'commit.' Not sure how to resolve. Oh, I also changed both views and forms to:        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        g = GeoIP()
        lat, lon = g.lat_lon('google.com')
        user_location = super(StoryForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user_location.latitude = lat
        user_location.longitude = lon
        user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)  (Cannot figure out how to format code in comments)

Comment: View: @login_required
def submit_story(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        story_form = StoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if story_form.is_valid():
            new_story = story_form.save(commit=False)
            new_story.author = request.user
            new_story.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/report/all/")
    else: # GET request
        story_form = StoryForm()
    return render_to_response("report/report.html", {'form': story_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: @WhyNot one thing at a time. That should be a different question. But I suggest you start reading here about model forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Thanks for the example and the reference. Unfortunately, it's not saving the author attribute any longer. This is the resulting error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: @WhyNot unfortunately I don't know what you've changed and I obviously can't read the code you posted on the comments. You should either try to read the official django docs on views, forms and requests or post a brand new question. In any case you're having a completely different error now and SO rules say it should be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... just to be sure... aren't there some obvious indentation errors in the code you've pasted?
What does your error exactly says?

**EDIT**: I believe that your error might be in the fact that **you are passing ip_address by name**, while you have it defined as a **positional** argument in the form *save()* method. Which looks like was also happening in the other answer that you linked, by the way... :)

Try changing this line in your code:

`def save(self, ip_address, *args, **kwargs)`

by this one:

`def save(self, ip_address=None, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Those missing indents were in the copying; it's fine in the actual code. This is the error:     'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: hmm... I'm too new to stackoverflow it seems... but don't see any "comment" link on the OP :/ re. question, do you have the right **cities** data file installed, and the right path set in your settings? (see [django geoip docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/))

Comment: The test code presented in the docs works in the shell, so it seems it's accessible. The import statement in the views is greyed out in PyCharm (which it does sometimes) but not in the forms.

Comment: Same error. pyCharm is highlighting the def save() arguments in the form with this alert: "Method signature does not match signature of base method." Not sure what the context of this is.